# Is there a default database that mysql uses in case we dont create one?

Tags: mysql, database

If I don't create a database the first time I use mySQL, will it give me an error? or use a default database?

Comment: What happens when you try?  It will likely have some system data, but it's not going to create an application database for you.  Why/how would it?  What are you trying to do and how is it failing?

Comment: Thanks.
I was only curious to know what would happen in such a situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell MySQL what database to use. This can be done in the connection string, by using the USE 'database' command or by specifying the database in the SQL query e.g SELECT * FROM mydatabase.mytable.

If there is no database, then you need to create one & add tables to it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks so much.